# exists any command for the following (using awk or sed)

Tags: awk, sed

hi guys i have this format text. (keep in mind that there are several registers)

> 1111-1 tax 100 otherCharge 200

is it possible to do this with awk or sed?

> 1111-1 tax 100

> 1111-1 otherCharge 200

where 1111-1 is like ID.

my possible solution was to separate it into two files ( one for ID, and second for charge) to later join them.

but it stayed like this

> 1111-1 tax 100
>
> otherCharge 200

i need to replicated the ID. into the second line

Comment: Regarding `keep in mind that there are several registers` - what is an example of a "register" in your sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl does nicely:

```
$ echo '1111-1 tax 100 otherCharge 200' | \
perl -n -e '@x=split;$n=shift(@x);while(@x){$a=shift(@x);$b=shift(@x);print "$n $a $b\n"}'
```

prints

```
1111-1 tax 100
1111-1 otherCharge 200
```

This will work with any number of field pairs after the initial ID in each line.  For example:

```
$ echo '1111-1 tax 100 otherCharge 200 yetAnotherCharge 27
2222-2 tax 999 otherCharge 42 noCharge 0' | \
perl -n -e '@x=split;$n=shift(@x);while(@x){$a=shift(@x);$b=shift(@x);print "$n $a $b\n"}'
```

produces

```
1111-1 tax 100
1111-1 otherCharge 200
1111-1 yetAnotherCharge 27
2222-2 tax 999
2222-2 otherCharge 42
2222-2 noCharge 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $1, $2, $3 ORS $1, $4, $5}' file
1111-1 tax 100
1111-1 otherCharge 200
```

or if you can have more than 2 tag-value pairs on a line:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $1, $i, $(i+1)}' file
1111-1 tax 100
1111-1 otherCharge 200
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution that should work on multiple registers so long as they are in the format presented.

```sh
sed -E ' s/(^[0-9]*-[0-9])(\s[a-zA-Z ]*\s[0-9]*)(\s[a-zA-Z ].*)/\1\2\n\1\3/' $file
```